# vb.net how to get rid of unwanted vblf char

Tags: vb.net, string, url, linefeed

Hi everyone can someone explain to me why he vblf character keeps getting in my string please? i use this code so i don't have to check if the http:// already exists in the string with an 'if'

```
url1 = "http://" + URL.replace("http://","").Split("/")(0) & strin2
```

the problem is the result url is like this :
    "http://" & vblf & 'the rest of the url
can anyone explain to me why the vblf keeps getting in my string?

Comment: the sample url dosn't matter, but if it can help, i only get this when i use the data from a csv file (that my same application has created), so now for each line of a file i do a replace(vblf,nothing) before i get the data in it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would really use the right tool for the job which seems to be the [`Uri` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
Dim url As String = "http://google.com/blah?foo=1"
Dim uri As Uri
If Uri.TryCreate(url, UriKind.Absolute, uri) Then
    Dim schemeAndHost As String = uri.Scheme + uri.SchemeDelimiter + uri.Host
End If
```

Result: `http://google.com`

If you don't know if the url contains the protocol you could use  the [`UriBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uribuilder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class:

```
Dim url As String = "google.com/blah?foo=1"
Dim schemeAndHost As String
Dim uri As Uri = Nothing
If uri.TryCreate(url, UriKind.Absolute, uri) Then
    schemeAndHost = uri.Scheme + uri.SchemeDelimiter + uri.Host
ElseIf url.Contains("/") Then
    uri = New UriBuilder("http", url.Remove(url.IndexOf("/"))).Uri
    schemeAndHost = uri.Scheme + uri.SchemeDelimiter + uri.Host
End If
```

(same result)

Comment: thank you, even if i don't have to use this right now since i discovered the source of the problem, but i might still need it later